# How to define a Kendo Grid Schema model for the described scenario?

Tags: wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, odata, kendo-ui

I am stuck in the process of consuming my Data service ODATA response using Kendo Grid. The problem is that, I am not able to arrive at a schema model that fits the response.

Please find the JSON response of my service.

```
{
  "d" : [{
    "__metadata": {
      "uri": "http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc/Order('4345')", 
      "type": "DataModels.OrderDetail"
    }, 
    "ItemList": [{
      "__metadata": {
        "uri": "http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc/Item('1')", 
        "type": "DataModels.Item"
      }, 
      "ItemId": "1", 
      "Name": "TestItem", 
      "Rate": "19.00", 
      "Quantity": "3"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Need some suggestion / help that can let me move forward in this effort.

Comment: Are you using the Kendo DataSource as in the following blog post? http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-08-23/cross-domain_queries_to_odata_services_with_jquery.aspx

Comment: Yes. I am using the "Using the Kendo UI Data Source" way of achieving this. But, my problem is that I just want to have a grid populate only the ItemList value which is currently wrapped inside an ItemList section. So, I am trying to define a model such that Kendo Grid can consume the value inside the ItemList.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
schema: {
      data: "d.ItemList"
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I have tried this option but dint work.